# Pre-filtering OData using an URL param (

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I'm using odata with web API on service fabric.
I would like to do some per-filtering using a parameter in the URL before to return the IQuerable. Probably that means that I'm mixing the API routing with the odata routing. A not-working example, just to give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(IQuerable<Something>))]
[HttpGet, Route("Something/{id:guid}/SomeFiltrableList")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBySomethingId(Guid id)
{
  var someFiltrableList= await _repository.GetSomething(id);

  return Ok(someFiltrableList.AsQueryable());
}
```

Would it be possible to do something like this? How?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions` parameter and apply it to the data source:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(IQueryable<Something>))]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet, System.Web.Http.Route("Something/{id:guid}/SomeFiltrableList")]
public async Task<IQueryable<Something>> Get(Guid id, ODataQueryOptions options)
{
    var someFiltrableList = await _repository.GetSomething(id);

    return options
                .ApplyTo(someFiltrableList)
                .Cast<Something>()
                .AsQueryable();
}
```